# Issue with Open VPN connection which specifies a .252 subnet mask

Tags: openvpn, netmask

I'm connecting OK wirelessly to my office VPN (with Open VPN client) using my Windows 10 laptop.

I need access to devices 10.10.21.200 and 10.10.21.123, and the Open VPN service has assigned me an IP address of 10.10.21.6.

However, I can't ping those two devices.

I've just noticed that the adapter interface for this connection (Ethernet #2), whilst it provides 10.10.21.6 as an IP address, specifies a subnet mask of 255.255.255.252. Am I right in thinking that this will restrict me to access only 10.10.21.5 and 10.10.21.6 addresses ? Does this Open VPN subnet mask need changing to 255.255.255.0 ?

Comment: OpenVPN uses the `net30` topology by default when configured for layer 3. It emulates a peer-to-peer connection but is Windows-compatible.